# How to find factorials in expression (usually solved by GCMathParser)

Tags: ios, objective-c, calculator

I am using this [GCMathParser](https://github.com/xslim/GCMathParser) for a calculator application. As **GCMathParser** doesn't support factorials, permutation etc, I've to find those operators (e.g !, nPr) manually and replace them with the result.
How can I implement this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) instead?  It comes with support for factorial built-in, and [has a simple API for adding new functions](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Adding-New-Functions).

Comment: thank you sir ! i just saw it works well for factorial too, but for functionality of permutation, i'm still stuck to the same problem(to identify what values are to be used as 'n' and 'r' in 'nPr' for calculation) As there can be many cases of using nPr in an expression. :(

Comment: By far the simplest solution is to define a function `nPr(x,y)` using `-[DDMathEvaluator registerFunction:forName]:`.  If you want to make `nPr` act like an infix operator, that will still be easier with `DDMathParser` than with `GCMathParser`.  You'll need to add `nPr` as an operator token and modify the parser to recognize it.

Comment: And if you haven't found it already, here's a way you can create an nCr function for DDMathParser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17325997/115730

Comment: that's a pretty good way sir, but i can't ask user to enter expression like    nPr(5,2)  it have to be the way 5nPr2 or 5P2 . For that even if i use DDMathParser, i'll have to either convert my expression to that (nPr(5,2)) way, or calculate factorials manually and if i have to do that then i think it'd be easy to stick to GCMathParser. With all respect, thanks to you both sir, for me it's time to go native :)

Comment: @nickAtStack You could define a new binary operator of `nPr` or `P`, and that would let you have that syntax.  You would do that by modifying the [list of defined operators](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/blob/master/DDMathParser/_DDOperatorInfo.m#L96) to insert the operator at the appropriate precedence. You'd also need to (of course) define the nPr function.